# I am trying to replace text in a specific cell using logic

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code i have used so far, it is removing the "p" but not putting in the text like i expected. What might I be doing wrong? I have already dim my titles and those work

```
If copySheet.Range("B2") = "p" Then
copySheet.Range("B2").Value = “POW”
  End If

  If copySheet.Range("B2") = "c" Then
copySheet.Range("B2").Value = “CAP”
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is this a copy directly from the vbe.  do you see the stylized quotes: `“”`  they need to be replaced with regular quotes.

Comment: @ScottCraner I find this interesting; if you query the value of anything in those stylized quotes it returns Empty with no errors assigning to a string or variant, what is VBA doing here?

Comment: Thank you so much, Im not sure how those got in there. Im self taught as needed so there is a lot i dont know. Huge help Scott thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way i can use a similar macro that would encompass a whole column?

Comment: Look into Range.Replace.

Comment: `copySheet.Range("B:B").Replace "p", "POW", xlWhole`

Comment: @Absinthe I honestly do not know why it is doing that.  Greater minds than mine will need to explain.

Comment: I had looked into, unfortunately i dont understand whats happening and am unable to flex it to my needs accordingly

Comment: ohhh, thanks scott

Comment: I tried that last code you sent and it works perfect for my needs. Thanks again Scott

Comment: I will write up an answer.

Comment: Thanks again Scott, I now have a document that pretty much runs, saves and shuts itself down and prints beautifully everytime.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the stylized quotes `“POW”` they need to be replaced with regular quotes.

But to do the full column at once just use `Range.Replace()`

```
copySheet.Range("B:B").Replace "p", "POW", xlWhole
```

If you have a list to replace I would fill two arrays, one with what to replace and what to replace with.  Then loop the array and do the replace:

```
Dim fnd As Variant
fnd = Array("p", "c")

Dim outpt As Variant
outpt = Array("POW", "CAP")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(fnd) To UBound(fnd)
    copySheet.Range("B:B").Replace fnd(i), outpt(i), xlWhole
Next i
```

Now you just need to update the arrays.